# Android's Material Design of Toolbar / SupportActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, material-design, android-toolbar

I'm experimenting with the news themes tonight and I'm wondering if anyone knows these fix to this issue.

This appears on the stock [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) and even, as seen below, when referring to custom layout file.

It's relatively minor but my OCD eyes go right to it so maybe someone can help. Thanks :)

[image: Screenshot of cropped subtitle descenders.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Inheriting from the correct theme and declaring attributes in pairs (with and without the `android:` prefix) was the fix!

```
<!-- Base app theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles. -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>

    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarSubTitleText</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarSubTitleText</item>

    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarSubTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/subtitle</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If es0329's answer doesn't work for you, try to replace *titleTextStyle* by *titleTextAppearance*. It is working for me:

```
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
        <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>

        <item name="android:subtitleTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBarSubTitleText</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBarSubTitleText</item>

        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
    </style>
```